# Выравнивание двух и более строк по вертикали

Tags: html, css

Как сделать выравнивание нескольких строк по вертикали (по высоте блока), чтобы строки находились в центре и шли по порядку. Есть ли какой-то способ?

Comment: Абстракции хороши для понимания концепций, реальные проблемы необходимо озвучивать конкретно. На расплывчатый вопрос - общий ответ: заюзайте `Flex`.

Comment: @Other, то есть, применять display: flex к p?

Comment: @Андрей, да к чему угодно, главное чтобы было свойство `display` у акцептора :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div.container {
  display: flex; // новое свойство, подробнее по ссылке*
  flex-flow: column wrap; // каждый элемент внутри контейнера начинается с отдельной строки
  align-items: center; // вертикально по центру
  justify-content: center; // горизонтально по центру
  width: 500px; // эти 3 свойства - чтобы увидеть в действии, не обращайте внимание, они в данном примере роли не играют
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Одна линия...</p>
  <p>2 линии...</p>
  <p>Да хоть 5 линий текста</p>
</div>
```

*[ссылка](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/)

---

Кстати говоря, выравнивать можно не только при строго известной высоте. Подойдут также проценты. Единственное, о чем, пожалуй, не стоит забывать, это то, что, чтобы элемент выровнялся в родителе по центру вертикально, родитель вертикально должен быть больше дочернего э-та. Но это, думаю, итак понятно.

Comment: Кстати говоря, пример внутри этого фрейма не работает. Но у меня все отлично: http://imgur.com/QPZsF3L